# What happend with "myopenid" login method?

Tags: discussion, support

I don't know if it's happening just to me, but since yesterday I'm not enabled o login with "myopenID"(from www.myopenid.com) method. It just desapeared from login options:

[image]

What happened to it?

Comment: Getting error? Silent failure? Etc? You'll need to be a bit more specific about the exact problem.

Comment: Why vote to close and downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the ***Show more login options...*** text underneath the four main buttons.

Here you'll find small icons for a number of other provides (including MyOpenID when I look at the options on another site), plus the option to enter your OpenID's URL, so that SE supports *any* valid OpenID provider.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot added ;)

Comment: Thanks @iglvzx, t'was at work at the time and I'm still yet to bother working out how to screenshot properly on the Mac they've given me :)

Comment: It's ⇧⌘4 by the way :P

Comment: @slhck yeah, I've looked up the combo several times before, but every time I've then actually *needed* it later on (which, in my defense, is pretty infrequently) I've forgotten what it was >.< I just haven't managed to get the combo to stick in mind yet...